# Issues Redirecting to external link using flask/python

Tags: python, html, flask

I am working on a project and am relatively new to flask. I have a python script that outputs a data frame and this all works fine with my HTML code. The issue I am having is that I need to reroute to an external link. My flask code works fine if I output a link to a site such as variable = "www.google.com" but it does to work correctly with variable = prediction['Link'][0]. I get http://127.0.0.1:5000/stringOutputofPrediction instead of  http://stringOutputofPrediction Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours now.
Here is my html code:

```
  <div class="inner">
       <h3>{{prediction['Episode'][0]}}</h3>
       <p>{{prediction['Description'][0]}}</p>
       <a href= "{{ url_for('go_outside_flask_method', variable = prediction['Link'][0]) }}" >Watch</a>
  </div>
```

Flask/Python Script:

```
@app.route('/<string:variable>',)
def go_outside_flask_method(variable):
    variable = 'https://'+ variable
    return redirect(variable, code = 307)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would do something like this

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/redirect_to')
def redirect_to():
    link = request.args.get('link', '/')
    new_link = 'http://' + link
    return redirect(new_link), 301
```

Notice, that I do not expect the `link` in my link, I expect it in the `request.args` where I extract it and redirect client to a new link that is outside of the flask application. Also if the link is not provided, then I redirect to the `index` page.

And the `HTML` would be like this

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="{{ url_for('redirect_to', link='google.com')}}">Redirect me to</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.s. you should make sure that your `variable = prediction['Link'][0])` is really what you expect `stringOutputofPrediction`, try to debug when getting `variable/link` to the back-end `redirect_to` route.